# Do I have to use Arduino IRRemote libraries?

Tags: arduino-ide, ir

I have seen some tutorials to build your own IR Remote. But all of them use a library that contains the IR code. The question is, could I just skip, injecting a library and make the Arduino output a IR signal?

Comment: Sure. If you *really* want to spend the time needed to both understand the IR protocol and write the code to generate the right signals.

Comment: it is fairly simple if you only want to emulate one remote control and only a few buttons ...... have you researched the TV remote control IR protocol? .... do you have any experience with an Arduino?

Comment: I dont even have a single Arduino. I thought it would be easier, but the libraries include the ir codes? Because I need ALL Power off ir codes.

Comment: google `tv-b-gone`   .... https://github.com/shirriff/Arduino-TV-B-Gone